# Can anyone please explain why is this android layout not working and crashes the activity as soon as the activity is launched

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout, cardview

This code is not working and the app is crashed all the time. Whenever I run the code, it shows an error. Even after can anyone please help me to remove this error.
This error is also occuring whenever I am using TextInputLayout in my app.

**Gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.weatherapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**Error Log**

**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.weatherapp, PID: 18681
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weatherapp/com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML
>   file line #21: Error inflating class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>           at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:48)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable with resource ID
>
> ```
>  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/secondary_text_light_nodisable.xml from drawable resource ID
>
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
>     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:638)
>     at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:316)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:900)
>     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
>     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
> ```
>
> 2020-04-21 19:19:16.157 18681-18681/com.example.weatherapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.(View.java:4784)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:597)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:92)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:87)
>           at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.(CardView.java:121)
>           at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.(CardView.java:117)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>           at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:48)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
>        Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag
>   defining a drawable
>           at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:189)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.createFromXmlForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:1471)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:822)
>             ... 39 more
>   **
>   **XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#B0EEF6"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/iv_main"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/snowflake"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Weather"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_weather"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="condition"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey600"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_condition"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/iv_humid"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/humidity"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Degree"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_degree"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="per cent"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey600"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_percent"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/iv_temp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/temperature"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Minimum"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_minimum"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Maximum"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey600"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_maximum"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/iv_wind"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/wind"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Wind"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_wind"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="miles/hour"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey600"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_miles"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/location"
                        android:id="@+id/iv_location"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Name"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_name"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="country"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey600"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_country"/>


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:background="@color/quantum_grey" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sunrise"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="sunrise"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_sunrise"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sunset"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="sunset"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_sunset"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your crash log

Comment: It gives an error saying, error inflating androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

Comment: We need the complete stack trace, not just that one line from it.

Comment: also add your build.gradle

Comment: I have added the gradle and the error log in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add card view dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

and use

```
app:background="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
```

or

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light_nodisable"
```

Comment: replace android with app

Comment: The code did work for me after using this solution, Thank you!!

Comment: I'm happy to help